# Ktor server with my PC's public ip refuses to work

Tags: kotlin, server, ktor

I tried to run ktor server on my personal computer with my public IP. But server gave me an error.

Here is a kotlin code:

```
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.*
import io.ktor.server.netty.*
import io.ktor.server.response.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*

fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "<public IP of my PC>", module = Application::module)
        .start(wait = true)
}

fun Application.module() {
    routing {
        get("/") {
            call.respondText("Hello World!")
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the error that I get:

```
2023-10-09 15:22:39.256 [main] INFO  ktor.application - Autoreload is disabled because the development mode is off.
2023-10-09 15:22:39.638 [main] INFO  ktor.application - Application started in 0.415 seconds.
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:459)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:448)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:141)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:562)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:600)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:579)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:973)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:260)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:356)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.EventLoopGroupProxy$Companion.create$lambda$1$lambda$0(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:296)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I tried to find any information regarding using your own public IP for a personal server and the internet says it is possible but many internet providers can block it, but I am not sure whether mine blocks it.

The server on the local IP works fine.
I also checked several ports but I still got the same error.

Comment: Have you tried the host 0.0.0.0?

Comment: Yes. But the server starts to serve only on my local IP.